# Having trouble assigning values to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
namespace cs19 {

void counting_sort(int *array, unsigned array_len) {
  int lowest, largest, array_range, placer, num;
  int q = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < array_len; ++i) {
    if(i == 0) {
      lowest = array[i];
      largest = array[i];
    }
    if (largest < array[i]) largest = array[i];
    if (lowest > array[i]) lowest = array[i];
  }
  if(largest > -1 && lowest < 1) array_range = (largest - lowest) + 1;
  else {
    array_range = largest - lowest;
  }
```

Having trouble with the below part of my code I'm trying to make an array with a range of numbers from the smallest value to the largest. However, when I run my code it doesn't assign the numbers to the array. My teacher wants us to use pure c++ code without any other added functions or else I would of most likely used a vector.

```
  int *tally_array = new int[array_range];
  for (int j = lowest; j <= largest; ++j) {
    tally_array[q] = j;
    ++q;
  }
  num = 0;
  for (int g = 0; g < array_range; ++g) {
    for (int a = 0; a < array_len; ++a) {
      if(array[a] == tally_array[g]) {
        placer = array[num];
        array[num] = tally_array[g];
        array[g] = placer;
        ++num;
      }
    }
  }
  delete[] tally_array;
}

}
```

Comment: "pure C++" without using the other parts of C++, and using `new[]` and `delete[]`... sounds like you are in a very advanced C++ class.  Getting down-and-dirty with the unseemly underbelly of C++ and all the fiddly gory details.  3rd year C++?  4th?

Comment: Is this assignment about creating a home-made vector class, or about implementing a counting sort?  I really don't understand these nutty requirements that you can't use vector -- the counting sort isn't going to magically get written for you if you used vector.  It's courses and teachers with restrictions like this is the reason so many new programmers drop C++ and go to other languages, such as Python.

Comment: I recommend bashing this into a real [mre]. Currently I have questions like, "In the second code block, was `q` initialized to 0?" that would be non-questions with a complete example.

Comment: @user4581301 I assume it is the same piece of code split in half so it seems that it was initialised to 0.

Comment: Oh wait. The second block is a continuation of the first block, isn't it? In that case, a recommendation: Don't define a variable until you need it. This keeps the scope of the variable tight and keeps the cause and effects close together to make for easier reading. If you can put off defining a variable until you know it's starting value, you can initialize the sucker and not run the risk of using an uninitialized variable. For example, if `array_len` is 0, bad smurf will happen with `lowest` and `largest`.

Comment: Yes, it's a counting sort assignment.

Comment: yes, it's all written as one piece of code so q was initialized as 0.

Comment: Be worth your time looking into https://godbolt.org/z/jKGhY9esv Something marched out of range and trashed the array at `tally_array`.

Comment: I assume this is some error in the counting sort implementation and not c++ not placing the values in the array, in which case a debugger would help you greatly. Also I am not sure about the counting sort's finer details, but this seems like a very weird implementation to me (i.e. from what I can tell in a counting sort the last loop creating the sorted array should be a single loop)

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah the length of the array should be `largest-lowest+1`, but that would not stop the buffer overflows. https://godbolt.org/z/b9cnj7Gqa

Comment: I was wrong. `num` gets out of range, smashes the stack, and makes `tally_array` look like the villain. https://godbolt.org/z/zs9xfvsz5

Comment: My advice would be to start by getting the code working, using whatever would be most convenient (including vector). Then work on writing minimal replacements for those parts you're not allowed to use. As an aside, this code doesn't look very close to how I'd expect a counting sort to look.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me like your code implements (at least what I'd normally think of as) a counting sort.

So, to give an idea of the general kind of thing you're trying to accomplish, here's a counting sort (that works), but using all sorts of stuff your teacher apparently won't accept, so you can't turn it in directly.

```cpp
void counting_sort(int* array, unsigned array_len) {
    std::map<int, unsigned> tallies;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < array_len; i++)
        ++tallies[array[i]];

    unsigned pos = 0;
    for (auto [value, count] : tallies)
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            array[pos++] = value;
}
```

We start by walking through the input array, incrementing a count for each value in the input (in this case, just using a `map` as a sparse array).

Then we walk through the array of counts, and write the appropriate number of each value into the array, in order.

Here's a quick test:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int> inputs { 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0 };

    counting_sort(inputs.data(), inputs.size());

    for (int i : inputs)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

...and here's output from that test:

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 3
```

To reiterate the basic idea of the algorithm: we start with an array of counts. We use that to count the number of times each value in the input array occurs. Since it contains counts, each value in it should start out at zero. We walk through values in the input array, and use those to index into the tally array, incrementing the location in the tally array by one when we encounter a value.

When we're done with that, the first item in the array should contain the number of times the lowest value in the input occurred, the second number of times lowest+1 occurred (which may easily be 0), and so on.

Then we walk through the array of tallies. The index we're using is the value that came from the input array, and the value in the tally is the number of times that value occurred. So, we write that value out the appropriate number of times, then proceed to the next. When we reach the end of the array, we're done.

The big difference in your case is how we store the tallies. I've used a `map<int, unsigned>`, which acts like a sparse array--that is, although it *can* store a value associated with any int, it only really stores the values we've written there, so any value that wasn't in the input array won't be in our tally either.

To satisfy your teacher's proclivities, when you write it you're apparently going to use `new` to allocate a block of data using `new`<sup>1</sup>. So you will store all the intermediate values. You want to start with them all set to 0. Then when you encounter an input value, you use it as an index, and increment that value in the tallies array.

Then you'll do just about like above, walking through the tallies array, and writing values back to the input array the proper number of times. Since you started each count at zero, any that weren't present will be written out zero times, which translates to them not being written at all.